# Cannot display data from firebase with .where()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I'm trying to display data from firebase, it works very well but when I add the condition where() to compare uid to the id present in my database

However in the console.log, it appears well, it's as if between the user request and the getOrders() request; the delay was too short and that he didn't have time to find uid

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');

  useEffect( () => {
   fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        console.log(user);
            } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
    
    });
getOrders();
 
}, []);

 function getOrders() {
    fire.firestore().collection("orders")
    
    .where('uid', '==', `${user.uid}`)
    .where('statut', '==', 'Active')
    .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
      setOrders(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          orderid: doc.data().id,
          statut: doc.data().statut,
          nomproduit: doc.data().nomproduit
          
        }))
      );
    });
  }
```

[image]

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider passing the `uid` as an argument into `getOrders()` and call it when the `user` is ready. Like this

```js
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');

  useEffect( () => {
   fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        console.log(user);
        getOrders(user.uid);
            } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
    
    });
}, []);

 function getOrders(uid) {
    fire.firestore().collection("orders")
    
    .where('uid', '==', `${uid}`)
    .where('statut', '==', 'Active')
    .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
      setOrders(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          orderid: doc.data().id,
          statut: doc.data().statut,
          nomproduit: doc.data().nomproduit
          
        }))
      );
    });
  }
```

Another thing you could do would be to pass `user` as a dependency into the `useEffect()` hook like this

```js
useEffect( () => {
   fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        console.log(user); 
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
    
    });
   getOrders();
}, [user]);
```

This will cause the `useEffect` to run again when the user has changed. Not the best approach tho, performance wise, just FYI.